# Finding the age from a user input jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-input

I'm trying to have the user enter a year like 2030, it will take that and tell you that Bob is 34 since he was born in 1996. So I want the output to be "Bob is YEAR Inputted -  1996 in YEAR INPUTTED" (Bob is 34 in 2030.)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
          //year
            $("#year_button").on("click", function(){ //on click of year button 
              var inputYear = $("#yearborn").val();
              var age = inputYear - 1996;
              if(inputYear > 1996){
                $(".show-age").html("Bob is "+age+" Year old in "+inputYear+"");
              } else {
                $(".show-age").html("Please add a number more than 1996");
              }
            });
          </script>

        <div id="year">
              <p>Enter a Year: <input id="yearborn" type="number"/> 
              <div id="year_button">
                <button type="button" id="year_button">Enter</button> </p>
              </div>
        </div>

        <div class="show-age"></div>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @RajanBenipuri Right now, when I click enter nothing happens. I think it has to do with it is looking for a month, day, and year. While I'm only using a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the code snippet.

```css
.form-wrap{
  display: flex;
}

.get-age{
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div id="year">
  <p>Enter a Year: <input id="yearborn" type="number" > 
      <button type="button" id="submityear">Enter</button> 
  </p>
</div>

<div class="show-age"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#submityear").on("click", function(){
  var inputYear = $("#yearborn").val();
  var age = inputYear - 1996;
  if(inputYear > 1996){
    $(".show-age").html("Bob is "+age+" Year old in "+inputYear+"");
  } else {
    $(".show-age").html("Please add a number more than 1996");
  }
});
</script>
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit :** Please try the new code and let me know if you still having any issue.

Comment: I tried this code and it didn't work. Nothing wrote but it works on this site

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your page?

Answer (score 0):

Few things from your posted code.

- Your script opening and closing syntax is not matching.
- Your textbox id is yearborn - `var inputYear = $("#year").val();`
- with jquery, you can trigger action of click button, so no need to add the `onclick="yearinputed()`. you haven't defined this function as well.

Below I have edited your code snippet and looks working.

```js
      $("#year_button").on("click", function(){ //on click of year button 
      var inputYear = $("#yearborn").val();
      var age = inputYear - 1996;
      if(inputYear > 1996){
        $(".show-age").html("Bob is "+age+" Year old in "+inputYear+"");
      } else {
        $(".show-age").html("Please add a number more than 1996");
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="year">
      <p>Enter a Year: <input id="yearborn" type="number"/> 
      <div id="year_button">
        <button type="button" id="year_button">Enter</button> </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="show-age"></div>
```

Comment: I took what you exactly put in my code and it wouldn't print anything out, but it working here

Comment: I updated your code in my question to show you what I entered in my code @Bee

Comment: Inpect your code again, inspect in the console and find where the error is. I believe its because of the jquery inclusions.

Comment: I'm checking my whole HTML doc because I have other code in my file